# Java Bean Machine Program not outputting correctly

Tags: java

I am working on this java project to simulate a bean machine or otherwise known as a plinko game etc. Basically what the program is supposed to do is ask the user how many balls they want to drop and how many slots they want at the bottom. It is then supposed to hit a peg and has a %50 chance of falling either left or right. It is then supposed to display the path of each ball such as: LRLLLRL etc. The final thing it does is displays a histogram of how the balls are stacked. I have gotten the path to display correctly but cannot get the right output of the histogram. Im thinking I have a small overlook of something causing it but I thought I'd come here to see if anyone could pinpoint it. If anyone could help out I would be really greatful.

Expected output:

```
Balls: 5  
Slots: 7  

LRLRLLR  
RRLRRRL  
RLRLLRR  
LRRLRLL  
LRLRLRR  

 0  
00 0 0
```

This output isnt correct but it gives the idea of what is supposed to happen. Its supposed to print the path of the ball and then print what the game would look like when all the balls have been dropped in and are stacked up.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class KedgeBean{
public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter the number of balls you want drop: ");

    int ball_number = input.nextInt();

    while(ball_number < 0)
    {
        System.out.print("Please enter a positive number: ");

        ball_number = input.nextInt();
    }

    System.out.print("Enter the number of slots in the machine: ");

    int slot_number = input.nextInt();

    while(slot_number < 0)
    {
        System.out.print("Please enter a positive number: ");

        slot_number = input.nextInt();
    }

    int[] slots_array = new int[slot_number];


    for(int i = 0; i < ball_number; i++)
    {
        slots_array[ball_path(slot_number)]++;
    }

    display(slots_array);       
}

/** Produces the output for the ball and also stores the position of the ball */
public static int ball_path (int slot_number)
{
    int ball_position = (slot_number / 2);

    for(int i = 0; i < slot_number; i++)
    {

        if(Math.random() * 10 <= 5)
        {
            ball_position++;

            if(ball_position >= slot_number)
            {
                ball_position--;
            }

            System.out.print("R");
        }

        else
        {
                    ball_position--;

            if(ball_position < 0)
            {
                ball_position++;
            }

            System.out.print("L");
        }
    }

    System.out.println();

    return ball_position;
}

/** display */
public static void display(int[] slots_array)
{
    int slot_height = maximum(slots_array);

    for(int i = slot_height; i > 0; i--)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < slots_array.length; j++)
        {
            if(slots_array[j] >= 1)
            {
                System.out.print("o");
            }

            else
            {
                System.out.print("-");
            }

        }
    System.out.println();
    }
}

/** Gets the maximum number in a slot */
public static int maximum(int[] slots_array)
{
    int max = slots_array[0];

    for(int i = 1; i < slots_array.length; i++)
    {
        if(slots_array[i] > max)
        {
            max = slots_array[i];
        }
    }

return max; 

}
}
```

Comment: Post expected and actual output, and always format your code; code with excessive blank lines is hard to read.

Comment: could you please explain the histogram's output?

Answer (score 0):

```
package deneme;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class BeanMachine {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the number of balls to drop: ");
        int numberOfBalls = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter the number of slots in the bean machine: ");
        int numberOfSlots = input.nextInt();

        int[] slots = new int[numberOfSlots + 1];
        String rotation;
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfBalls; i++) {
                int sum = 0;
                for (int j = 0; j < numberOfSlots; j++) {
                    int randomNumber = (int) (Math.random() * 2);
                    sum += randomNumber;
                    if (randomNumber == 0)
                        rotation = "L";
                    else
                        rotation = "R";
                    System.out.print(rotation);
                }
                slots[sum]++;
                System.out.println();
        }
        String[] ball = new String[numberOfSlots + 1];
        for (int i = numberOfBalls; i > 0; i--) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= numberOfSlots; j++) {
                if (i == slots[j]) {
                    ball[j] = "O";
                    slots[j]--;
                } else
                    ball[j] = " ";
                System.out.print(ball[j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's like dis.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BeanMachine {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the number of balls to drop: ");
    int numberOfBalls = input.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter the number of slots in the bean machine: ");
    int numberOfSlots = input.nextInt();

    int[] slots = new int[numberOfSlots + 1];
    String rotation;

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfBalls; i++) {

            int sum = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < numberOfSlots; j++) {

                int randomNumber = (int) (Math.random() * 2);
                sum += randomNumber;
                if (randomNumber == 0)
                    rotation = "L";
                else
                    rotation = "R";
                System.out.print(rotation);
            }
            slots[sum]++;
            System.out.println();
    }

    String[] ball = new String[numberOfSlots + 1];
    for (int i = numberOfBalls; i > 0; i--) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= numberOfSlots; j++) {
            if (i == slots[j]) {
                ball[j] = "O";
                slots[j]--;
            } else
                ball[j] = " ";
            System.out.print(ball[j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```